# Parsing DICOM files in a directory with GDCM

Tags: dicom

If I have a directory which contains a volumetric data from a variety of sources, say PET and a 4D CT. I know how for any given dataset to use say, [vtkGDCMImageReader](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/classvtkGDCMImageReader.html), to load a 3D image from a series of files. To handle multiple modalities and/or 4D datasets I am currently just manually peeking at tags and dividing up the files into lists and parsing them separately.

Is there a particularly general way of going this or even better a method within GDCM ? What I am doing seems to work but feels like a bit of a hack and there must be a *proper* way of doing it, I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can checkout the [following example](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/VolumeSorter_8cxx-example.html)